# transform "set" function to True/False

Tags: python, set

Hello I would like to know if it was possible to know if in a list if in the 1st case have several duplicates to return "True" if not in the 2nd case "False"?

Exemple :

```py
import random

list = []
word = ""
a = 0

while a < 10 :
    for i in range(0,10):
        word = word + str(random.randint(0,9))
        i = i + 1
    list.append(word)
    word = "" #reset
    print(list)
    a = a + 1
# it's just an example it's not my real program
# and from that I would like to know if in my list
# there are duplicates by returning False or True.
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use a set and compare its length with the original list:

```
if len(set(yourList)) < len(yourList):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for duplicates then try something like:

```
if len(my_list) != len(set(my_list):
    return "Your list contains duplicate values"
else:
    return "The values in your list are unique"
```

If you only want to test that there are no duplicates of the first item in the list then try using `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

my_count = Counter(my_list)

if my_count[my_list[0]) > 1:
    return True
else:
    return False
```